# What is a good Pokémon team in X/Y for Singleplayer purposes?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I want to train up a good team in order to beat the Pokémon League and various trainers in-game. I'm not focusing on competitive (online) play at the moment, so I'm only asking for some suggestions for a good in-game Pokémon team.

I'm not looking directly for 6 "must have" Pokemon, just a suggestion of **some good Pokémon** to train (it could be 6/8/10 Pokémon etc) or some Pokémon **types** to have in my Pokémon team.

Comment: Anything would work. Level them up enough and you can beat the game with any pokemon you want. There is some dude who beat the elite four with a magicarp... That wasn't x/y though.

Comment: @Arperum I know, but I also want a good/competitive team.

Comment: Uhm, find a good HM slave or two, train up a smeargle into a [catching machine](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/145371/30115) and the rest is up to you. The trainers in-game (With a few notable exceptions) and the elite four are all jokes this gen.

Comment: As for Sterno's edit I edited my answer, too. Look at "//EDIT2". Maybe this helps you a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry to give you that answer, but: It doesn't matter!

Since the first Pokémon games (Red/Blue/Green) gameplay mechanics were really simple. As you have endless tries to defeat opponent trainers, you are also able to train your Pokémon to oblivion.
So if you can't beat on first time, just level 5 levels further and you go. In 6th generation, story mode has been made even more easier.

Sure, there are some little tips:

- Try to get a counter for each type (you can look up on effectiveness tables like [this (German)](http://www.pokewiki.de/Typen#ab_6._Generation) to see which one counters).
- Try not to focus on one type one one Pokémon. If you've got a water Pokémon, don't only teach him water type attacks. It maybe can learn ice type or others which can then be used to counter other Pokémons.
- Prepare for Gym Leaders. Read the signs or ask NPCs what type the next Gym Leader uses. Battle against him/her once to see which Pokémon he/she uses. If you got it, learn your Pokémon counter-attacks or even switch them with more effective ones.

For story mode there is no "perfect team" as you can win with every team. You can choose your own team of your own favor.
It really begins to matter if you want to compete online - there you have to counter sets of Pokémon, strategy and tactics. But that's a whole different story.

As you want suggestions for some good Pokémon: As it is totally opinion-based for story mode I can't tell you "the three you must have". You see a Pokémon you like? Catch it, train it, try it. You're not happy with it? Replace it. This game is full of grindiness and you should experience this, too.

As for type suggestions I do have another link: [Click here](http://www.pokewiki.de/Rangliste_der_Typanf%C3%A4lligkeit)
Unfortunately I do have this table only in German, but I'll translate the introducing text for you:

> In this ranking, types are ordered by how well they can put away
>   attacks of all types (including double types). Morphers and Mega
>   Pokémons are included in count [ger *Anzahl*]

Please note, that this won't make your team good at the second thought. *Grass* type may be the worst type in attack and defense - but it may be wunderful if the opponent's team consists of "strong" *Ground* and *Water* types.

Comment: It's not the answer that I want, but you convince me :)

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes, I know, but as I said... there is no "three must-haves". You also see very "bad" Pokémon in competitive play which, through tactics, become strong enemies.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

- An **Electric** type (probably Jolteon or Raichu),
- A **Steel** type (Honedge evolutions or Steelix would be good),
- A **Fire** type (I would suggest the heat Rotom form),
- A **Water** type (Greninja would be good if you chose Froakie as your starter),
- A **Psychic** type (I have Meowstic and everything is going well),
- A **Flying** type (I don't know what a good Flying type would be, this is just incase you need to have a sky battle.)

Comment: Why would you have these types?  You're telling us which you'd use, which is a good start, but a great answer to this question would include the why.

Comment: I think it's good to note that Pokemon can have dual types as well. Greninja is a good choice due to its Water/Dark typing, but also Charizard or Talonflame are both Flying/Fire. If you go with Heat Rotom AND Jolteon/Raichu, you're also doubling up your Electric typing. Ralts would be a good Psychic type as it now doubles with Fairy, which you could use to get used to what Fairy is good/bad against.

Answer (score 0):

This list is from personal experiance and based off of my opinion, so please don't feel offended if any of these pokemon are not that good ^-^"

- **Chesnaught**: He's a very solid Pokemon, in both Attack AND Defense. He can take a few hits, and throw them right back at the offender. His move set was/is 
  Hammer Arm; Seed Bomb; Dragon Claw; Poison Jab.

  - Hammer Arm was used PERFECTLY against most of Wikstroms team, and I switched out for the Klefki.
- **Blastoise:** Again, another solid yet strong Team Member. He completely crushed Malva's team, and even the Klefki on Wikstroms team. He also took out the Tyrantrum on Diantha's team, and some of the Dragons on Drasnas team with his Ice Beam and Blizzard.  His move set is/was 
  Blizzard; Ice Beam; Surf; WaterFall.
- **Lucario:** (Not the one you get. I caught and trained one with +Attack and -Speed): A very speedy and strong team member. GREAT in Attack and Special Attack. He wiped out most of Drasna's team, and even beat Diantha's Mega Gardevoir with his Mega form + Poison Jab. His move set is/was 
  Close Combat; Dragon Pulse; Aura Sphere; Poison Jab.

  - He is a very solid team member, and you should really use him :3
- **Talonflame:** Again, a very speedy and attack based team member. He was very good against most of the Elite Four members with his attack and speed alone, but can be used to kill most of Wikstroms team (If you prefer) and the Gourgeist on Dianthas team. His move set is/was 
  Flame Charge; Fly; Brave Bird; Acrobatics.

  - I really sugest you to use him, cause he'll plow through anything, and can be very useful if you wanna do a Rematch on the Elite Four.
- **Absol:** A very Attack based pokemon. She's not the best, but is very good. She was used to help beat most of Siebolds team with the ThunderBolt and Thunder TM she had equiped to her. Her move set is/was 
  Perish Song (Last resorts); Slash; Thunder; Thunderbolt
- **Jolteon:** A very good pokemon if you want to speed through the Elite Four's pokemon with a series of Special-based moves. He was used to also kill most of Siebolds team with Thunderbolt and other electric type moves. He was also used to figt Dianthas Hawlucha with his eletric attacks. His move set is/was 
  Thunder; Thunder Bolt; Pin Missle; Discharge

Comment: I agree with most of this, it's a pretty solid team. The only thing I would change is Absol - You've already got Electric coverage with Jolteon, You'd be better running something like Sucker Punch (to make up for Absol's low speed, AND get the Dark STAB), and Psycho Cut to take advantage of Absol's high Physical attack. But otherwise this is a pretty balanced team

Answer (score -1):

My Team was

- Greninja ( evs 252 speed,252 spatk and 6 HP)

  - nature Timid
  - ability protean ( got in a trade)
  - moves: ice beam,surf,dark pulse,extrasensory
- Talonflame ( evs 252 atk 252 speed and 6 hp)

  - nature: Adamant
  - ability Gale wings ( got in trade)
  - moves: fly,flame charge,steel wing and brave bird
- Gardevoir ( evs 252 spatk 252 speed and 6 spdef)

  - nature Modest:
  - ability synchronoise
  - moves: Moonblast,Thunderbolt,psyhic,shadow ball
- Lucario ( evs 252 speed 252 attack and 6 Hp)

  - nature adamant
  - ability inner focus
  - moves: blaze kick,bullet punch,aura sphere,shadow claw
- Venusaur: ( evs 252 HP,252 def and 6 spdef)

  - nature calm
  - ability overgrow
  - moves: Toxic,Venoshock,sleep powder,energy ball
- Aggron ( evs 252 atk 252 def and 6 hp)

  - nature adamant
  - ability rock head
  - moves, double edge,iron defence,earthquake,iron head

Comment: Ok, so *why* is this team good?  Just telling us what is a good start, but a great answer will include why, as well.

Answer (score -1):

I'm plowing through the game currently and haven't beat the last gym yet , but overall I think my team is great. I can't remember the movesets but I have planned this so it's easy to win. I have...

- Delfox
- Raichu
- Aerodactyl
- Lapras
- Krookodile
- Toxicroak

Sorry for the inconvenience of no movesets I might post again later with my final team after I beat the elite four.

Comment: Would be better if you could add the 'why' it's great, because literally _any_ in-game team works... in-game!

Answer (score -1):

I beat the Pokemon league with:

- Chesnaugth

  - Wood hammer
  - Power up punch
  - -Solar beam
  - Hammer arm
- Charzard (Mega X)

  - Flame thrower
  - Fly
  - Arial ace
  - Fire fang
- Lapras

  - Water fall
  - Surf
  - Hydro pump
  - Sheer cold
- Aegislash

  - Shadow claw
  - Iron head
  - Sacred sword
  - Night slash
- Sylveon

  - Last resort
  - Moon blast
  - Cut
  - Thunder? (can't remember)

The last Pokemon I used was a lucario (Mega) but it was covered by others in my party so I'd recommend a Alakazam (Mega) instead.