# Easy way to earn money on Pokemon Omega Ruby/Alpha Sapphire?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I've recently been attempting to complete the Hoenn pokedex. I need *a lot* of pokéballs and ultra balls to *catch em' all*. If anyone knows an easy way to do this please simply explain it. I believe that repeatedly challenging the Elite Four may work, but I don't really want to do that.

Comment: Though this doesn't increase money, what you could do is save before trying to capture a particular pokemon, then try to capture it. If you fail, simply choose a previous save and try again. This doesn't help if you spam many ultrballs just to try to capture one pokemon.

Comment: The fastest way I know of to make money is to battle. The Elite 4 should award you with quite a pretty sum of money. If it's just Ultra Balls you need to buy, then money shouldn't be much trouble, even without beating the Elite 4. I've just beaten the Team Aqua base and have over 50 Ultra Balls in my inventory and enough money to buy 50 more of them.

Comment: Go to the Elite 4 with a Pokemon holding a Amulet coin. Then you would have an increased amount of money earned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should give **[Amulet Coin](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/In-battle_effect_item)** or **[Luck Incense](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Incense#Luck_Incense)** to your lead Pokemon.

O-Powers can help you, too. **Prize Money Power** that raises the money gained from a trainer battle, and **Bargain Power** that decreases the amount of money you have to spend on items.

Comment: I don't know where to find the Amulet coin. Yes I have the O-powers but the *Amulet Coin* sounds more interesting

Comment: As Bulbapedia, you receive it from mom after obtaining 5th Badge.

Comment: If you prefer, the Luck Incense has the same effect.

Comment: @pinckerman I've just started the game and came across this beauty of an item :) spent all my money buying it but boy does it build back up! definite investment!

Comment: @SaturnsEye I'm glad it was useful :)

Answer (score 4):

#### Earning Money:

You can use these to earn more money:

1. Amulet Coin* or Luck Incense** (Make your lead Pokemon hold them, they do not stack)
2. Prize Money O-Power***

You can make the best use of them by re-challenging:

- Trainers (Check the AreaNav's 'People' function to find them)
- The Elite Four (also unlocks other goodies)
- The Food Court in Mauville City.
- Secret Base Trainers (AreaNav 'Bases')

#### Saving Money:

Having **more** money is all well and good, but what about spending less as well?

- Use Bargain O-Power for discounts (half-price at level 3)
- Buy Balls in groups of 10 each, to get the bonus Premier Ball as well.
- Pickup Pokemon will occasionally find a Great or Ultra Ball, depending on their level.

#### Catching Pokemon

Now, onto the crux of the issue, catching Pokemon efficiently, so as to waste less Pokeballs:

- Use a [Catcher Pokemon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/145371/28182). Sleep + False Swipe will make a lot of Pokemon easy to catch, even with regular Pokeballs.
- Use Catching O-Power.
- Make use of Quick Balls and Timer Balls****.

  - Quick Balls have a greatly boosted catch rate if thrown as the first move. Good for Pokemon that tend to flee.
  - Timer Balls have a greatly boosted catch rate if the battle has gone for 10 turns or longer. Good for Pokemon that don't want to stay in their Pokeball/Stay asleep

<sub>* You get Amulet Coin from your Mum after the 5th Gym Badge.

** You can purchase Luck Incense in Slateport City

*** O-Powers are unlocked through the 'Strange Men' in Mauville Pokemon Center. Keep interacting with them, exiting and returning to the Center as they leave.

**** Quick and Timer Balls can be purchased from Fallabor and Rustboro Marts respectively.</sub>

Comment: the formula for timer balls [was changed in gen V](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269640/what-is-the-correct-formula-for-timer-balls) so they're better than ultra balls from turn 4, and cheaper!

Answer (score 1):

**The best method is:**

- Get a Level 100 Pokemon, (Preferably one with a ton of attack, I usually use Dragonite)
- Get an amulet coin
- Give Dragonite the Amulet Coin
- Max out the prize money O-Power
- Go to the elites with your Dragonite holding the amulet coin and before each battle use the maximum Prize Money O-Power, After each battle you will get a ton of money.

Answer (score 0):

I normally go the the E4 for money, with an amulet coin, but I recently found out about the move Payday. All you need is a level 30 Mewoth and teach it payday. Every time you use payday you get 10x the level of the pokemon using payday. For example: If  a level 30 mewoth uses payday once you will get 300 Pokedollars. And Every time you use Payday in one battle it will add up. So if a level 30 Mewoth uses payday 10 times in one battle, you would get 3000 poke dollars. Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Use Level 1 Prize Money O-Power with Amulet Coin or Luck Incense fighting the E4 and Champion--as long as your Pokémon are strong enough, you can do it multiple times (~48600 Poke).

Also, utilize people with all-Chansey secret bases. Chansey gives more prize money, and if you couple it with the above strategy, it should up your return.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking for the same trainers that battle repeatedly. I used the Bargain O-Power to get myself some good bargains, and I suggest you do so unless you don't have the O-Power.

Answer (score 0):

Battling the rich boys over and over usually helps. Although if you battle them too many times, they start to get tough. The elite four are BIG money earners, so take every chance you get to beat them. Luck incense and amulet coins always work, especially at the pokemon league. Mauville food court is a place I recommend, you meet lots of trainers there and they always earn you lots. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Get a strong, maybe level 100 Pokémon. Give it the amulet coin and go to route 104, where there is both the lass and the rich boy. Activate prize money O-Power before each battle, and you can speed through the battle. I prefer my Aegislash using Sacred Sword, but any quick animation, powerful fighting type move works fine. At level one prize money, I could get 3 battles in. You do have to wait a bit for both the trainers to be ready and for the O-Power to charge. I got 17,640 per battle, and there's only 2 Pokémon per battle, so I guess it would be around 100k in under 10min, but like 5 min after that for the trainers to get ready, and a few more for the O-Power to charge.