# What is the correct formula for Timer Balls?

Tags: pokemon-series

I was looking into the mechanics of Poké balls, and there's a lot of conflicting information about how the bonus from timer balls is calculated.

Earlier than Gen 5, everywhere agrees that the bonus starts at 1 and increases by 1 every 10 turns, to a maximum of 4 at `t = 30`.
Bulbapedia gives a continuous formula:

```
C = (10 + T) / 10
```

but it's not clear whether that's supposed to be rounded down to the nearest integer.

From Gen 5 onwards, some places claim the calculation has changed to:

```
C = (1 + X * 1229/4096)
```

However, the majority of sites only mention the other formula.

So are these two formulae correct for their respective generations? Are either of them rounded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Generation III and IV

> (("Amount of turns passed in battle" + 10) ÷ 10)x
> [maximum 4×]

This means:

- 1× if less than 10 turns have taken place
- 2× if between 10 and 19 turns have taken place
- 3× if between 20 and 29 turns have taken place
- 4× if 30 or more turns have taken place

These are all *rounded* values.

As explained on [Dragonflycave](http://www.dragonflycave.com/capture.aspx):

> The Pokémon games prior to the fifth generation only work with integers. In practice, this essentially means that they round all numbers down, including at every intermediate step in a calculation.

#### Generation V and VI

> (1 + "number of turns passed in battle" * 1229/4096)×
> [maximum 4×]

This means you get approximately a 0.3 bonus each turn passed, up to 4x.

Other sources: [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Ball), [Smogon](http://www.smogon.com/ingame/guides/capture_mechanics), [Thonky](http://www.thonky.com/pokemon-heartgold-soulsilver/list-of-pokeballs)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40998/discussion-between-danmakugrazer-and-pinckerman).